# Async data from controller to directive: unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to achieve a directive with an isolated scope and a two way binding to the scope of a controller that asynchronously loads data.

Part of the html:

```
<body ng-app = 'authorGraph' ng-controller = 'GraphCtrl'>
<graph-dir/>
```

Javascript:

```
var authorGraph = angular.module('authorGraph', []);

authorGraph.directive('graphDir', function () {
return {
    scope: {
     graphData: '=' //two way binding 
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element) {
        //do something with D3.js to visualise the data here
    }
};
```

Browsing the internet, I found out that promises could do the trick (this code comes before the directive implementation)

```
authorGraph.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/',
    {
        controller: 'GraphCtrl',
        resolve: {
            getData: function ($http) {
                return $http.get('graph_data.json').then(function (data) {
                    return data;
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

authorGraph.controller('GraphCtrl', function GraphCtrl($scope, getData) {
    $scope.graphData = getData;
});
```

However, I am stuck on the error

> Unknown provider: getDataProvider <- getData

Answer (score 0):

```
authorGraph.controller('GraphCtrl', function GraphCtrl($scope, getData) {
    $scope.graphData = getData;
});
```

In the above code, when you inject something as dependency it will start looking for the appropriae provider. In your case, it's looking getDataProvider and it couldn;t find any service.

When you're using resolve, the returned resolve param will be avaiable in your `$scope` object. You need not inject that as dependency.

Above code should be:

```
authorGraph.controller('GraphCtrl', function GraphCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.graphData = $scope.getData;
});
```